# Delayed Job for ASP.NET to running async code?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, asynchronous

Is there a plugin or other to mimic [Rails Delayed Job](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/7/22/do-it-later-with-delayed-job) in ASP.NET? What's the best way to run async code or jobs in an ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 2):

asp.net-mvc has [async controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) that are used for the main use case for `delayed_job` (at least how I read it from [here](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/7/22/do-it-later-with-delayed-job), haven't used Rails for a couple years)

Otherwise, asp.net is still .Net, so you can use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to just do a fire and forget chunk of code.

Unless there is some specific feature of `delayed_job` that you are interested in that I am missing....

Comment: Delayed_job is persistent and also has easy to use syntax requirements